# How to properly use indexing in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a large database (400k~ documents) and every document looks like this:

```
        "_id" : "uMNYu6xhYHNr7dahB",
        "beatmapset_id" : 124192,
        "beatmap_id" : 316712,
        "approved" : -2,
        "total_length" : 0,
        "hit_length" : 0,
        "version" : "Normal",
        "file_md5" : "97c2355a4490d255adbdb89719e9b273",
        "diff_size" : 7,
        "diff_overall" : 10,
        "diff_approach" : 10,
        "diff_drain" : 10,
        "mode" : 0,
        "approved_date" : null,
        "last_update" : "2013-10-24 19:12:48",
        "artist" : "HTT",
        "title" : "listen",
        "creator" : "adeo03",
        "bpm" : 999,
        "genre_id" : 1,
        "language_id" : 1,
        "favourite_count" : 0,
        "playcount" : 0,
        "passcount" : 0,
        "max_combo" : 3639,
        "difficultyrating" : 0
```

I implemented search on a site that uses a lot of queries. Normal query looks like this:

```
db.beatmaps.find({ 
  mode: { $in: [ 0, 1 ] },
  approved: { $in: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
  genre_id: { $in: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 ] },
  last_update: { '$gte': '2007-01-01', '$lte': '2015-11-14' },
  difficultyrating: { '$gte': 0, '$lte': 10 },
  favourite_count: { '$gte': 0, '$lte': 9999999 },
  diff_approach: { '$gte': 0, '$lte': 10 },
  diff_size: { '$gte': 2, '$lte': 7 },
  diff_overall: { '$gte': 0, '$lte': 10 },
  diff_drain: { '$gte': 0, '$lte': 10 },
  bpm: { '$gte': 0, '$lte': 9999999 }
}).sort({last_update: -1});
```

I also added indexes for fields: `"artist"`, `"title"`, `"creator"`, `"mode"`, `"approved"`, `"language_id"`, `"genre_id"`, `"last_update"`, `"diff_size"`, `"diff_overall"`, `"diff_drain"`, `"diff_approach"`, `"total_length"`, `"bpm"`, `"favourite_count"` and `"difficultyrating"`.

But when I run `explain` on this query it returns that only `last_update` index was used and it scanned all document in the database. Shouldn't intersection work there? Why? Even if I add compound index for that single case, if user changes query that index will no longer work.
What should I do to optimize my queries?

Comment: "*Compound indexes doesn't work either*"—please elaborate on this. How exactly do compound indexes not work? Adding a compound index would be my solution here.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko For example, I have compound index for that exact case. It will work, but the user can change queries and that index will not work. Is this the only way to create index for every individual case?

Comment: Have you read this section? [Index Intersection and Sort](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort). This would explain why only the `last_update` index is used in your case: it's used for sorting. Are your result data sets large? Could you maybe apply sorting in the application code?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I use infinite scroll. At first there are 8 documents and when you scroll down it loads another 8. No I cannot.

Comment: Are there fields that are commonly used by your users? You could define compound indexes for several most-used cases.

Comment: I guess. Looks like it's the only solution for me.